# How to make React-Table React-Window combo fit inside a smaller wrapper div?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, infinite-scroll, react-table

I have a table with all the bells and whistles that react-table has to offer, but one of the requirements I have is to add **infinite-scroll-like** behaviour to the table and I saw the Virtual Rows example that certainly solves my problem. Unfortunately the styling is not as easy to implement as I thought.

I have a fork of the mentioned example where I am trying to make it work inside a smaller wrapper div... What I have works but is not good UX since the user cant see the position of the scroll until scroll horizontally to the right

[image]

See "working" example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-bush-q44n5)

Ideally I will have the scroll bar outside next to the body of the table like the photoshoped image below

[image]

But all my attempts to make this work have fail.

Comment: The problem is that you have a wrapper div with `overflow-y: hidden`, so you're never going to get a vertical scrollbar on that element. Maybe try changing it to `overflow: auto` and playing around with `position: sticky` on the header elements to make them stay at the top when you scroll down.